# Ramda or ES6 - Return the value of an Object Property, after filtering an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I want to return one of the properties of an object, if the value of another property matches a constant.

Examples:

```
// The Array
[
 {name: "Name1", description: "Name1 Description", enabled: true},
 {name: "Name2", description: "Name2 Description", enabled: false},
 {name: "Name3", description: "Name3 Description", enabled: false}
]

// The Constant
enum constant {
  Name1 = 'Name1',
  Name2 = 'Name2',
  Name3 = 'Name3'
}

// What I want to return
// Value of enabled property, for the matching object
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
const filterBasedOnToggle = (featureTogglesArray: IFeatureToggle[], featureToggle: Toggle): boolean[] => {
  return featureTogglesArray.filter((feature: IFeatureToggle) => feature.name === featureToggle).map(featureProperty => featureProperty.enabled);
};
```

This as you can see by the Typings, is returning an Array of Boolean value. I want to return the plain value. Any Ideas? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't check if your code works, but as you said it returns a boolean array, so try using `array.find` to get the first match.

```js
  const MATCH = featureTogglesArray.find((feature: IFeatureToggle) => feature.name === featureToggle);
  return MATCH === undefined ? false : MATCH.enabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
const filterBasedOnToggle = (toggles) => (searchName) => {
  const feature = toggles .find (({name}) => name == searchName) || {}
  return feature .enabled
}

const featureToggles = [{name: "Name1", description: "Name1 Description", enabled: true}, {name: "Name2", description: "Name2 Description", enabled: false}, {name: "Name3", description: "Name3 Description", enabled: false}];

const enabledByName = filterBasedOnToggle (featureToggles);

console .log (['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4'] .map (enabledByName))
//~> [true, false, false, undefined]
```

This version uses `find` instead of `filter` to match on only the first one ... which was probably the signature issue with your version.  It returns `undefined` if the value isn't matched, but you could easily make that `false` if you liked.  You could of course write this with Ramda functions, but I don't see much there that would make this much simpler.

Comment: Not this stills returns an Array. Maybe I was not accurate enough. I want a single value returned. Not an array of them..

Comment: @DimitrisEfst: That array was simply demonstrating what happened with four values.  A single call returns a single value.  `enabledByName('Name1')` returns `true`, `enabledByName('Name2')` returns `false`, etc.